# Prove that a type of system is always consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have a problem in which I am trying to prove that a binary symmetric reflexive matrix is always consistent in a system mod 2 where the matrix is augmented with
$$
  \left[\begin{array} \\
    1 \\
    \vdots \\
    1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Such matrix is constructed like so:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
1 & a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \dots & a_{1,n} & 1 \\
a_{1,1} & 1 & a_{2,1} & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{1,2} & a_{2,1} & \ddots & a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n} & 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & a_{n-1,n-1} & 1 & a_{n,n} & 1 \\
a_{1,n} & \dots & a_{n-1,n} & a_{n,n} & 1 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

For example, a 3 by 3 matrix like this:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
When we reduce it using reduced row echelon form (RREF), we get:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
This system therefore has an infinite number of solutions, it is consistent. You can try it out with any other binary symmetrical matrix with a diagonal of ones and you'll always find at least one solution.

If you have a proof, an idea, or a suggestion on how to proceed, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't bijectivity already guarantee this? Also, the matrix in your example isn't bijective.

Comment: Sorry, wrong word, I ment reflexive.